# Reorder a list based on regular expression matches in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I would like to reorder a list of strings (column headers from Pandas) in Python 2.7.13 based on a regular expression. The desired output will have the current 0 index item in the same place, followed immediately by the matched strings found using the regular expression, followed by the remaining strings.

```
# Here's the input list:
cols = ['ID', 'MP', 'FC', 'Dest_MP', 'Dest_FC', 'Origin_MP', 'Origin_FC']

# And the desired output:
output_cols = ['ID', 'FC', 'Dest_FC', 'Origin_FC', 'MP', 'Dest_MP', 'Origin_MP']
```

I have a working code example. It's not pretty, and that's why I'm here.

```
import re

cols = ['ID', 'MP', 'FC', 'Dest_MP', 'Dest_FC', 'Origin_MP', 'Origin_FC']

pattern = re.compile(r'^FC|FC$')
matched_cols = filter(pattern.search, cols)

indices = [0] + [cols.index(match_column) for match_column in matched_cols]

output_cols, counter = [], 0
for index in indices:
    output_cols.append(cols.pop(index - counter))
    counter += 1

output_cols += cols

print(output_cols)
```

Is there a more readable, more pythonic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate first element, no way around that.

Then, on the rest of the list, use a sort key which returns a couple:

- first priority a boolean to indicate it matches the regex or not (negated so it appears first)
- second priority the element itself to tiebreak matching/non matching elements

like this:

```
import re

cols = ['ID', 'MP', 'FC', 'Dest_MP', 'Dest_FC', 'Origin_MP', 'Origin_FC']

new_cols = [cols[0]] + sorted(cols[1:],key=lambda x : (not bool(re.search("^FC|FC$",x)),x))
```

result:

```
['ID', 'Dest_FC', 'FC', 'Origin_FC', 'Dest_MP', 'MP', 'Origin_MP']
```

if you want `FC` to appear first, add a third value to the returned key. Let's choose the length of the strings (not clear what you really want to see as a tiebreaker

```
key=lambda x : (not bool(re.search("^FC|FC$",x)),len(x),x)
```

result is now:

```
['ID', 'FC', 'Dest_FC', 'Origin_FC', 'MP', 'Dest_MP', 'Origin_MP']
```

note that `sort` is stable, so maybe you don't need a tiebreaker at all:

```
new_cols = [cols[0]] + sorted(cols[1:],key=lambda x : not bool(re.search("^FC|FC$",x)))
```

result:

```
['ID', 'FC', 'Dest_FC', 'Origin_FC', 'MP', 'Dest_MP', 'Origin_MP']
```